# Calling a function inside itself to check for wrong input with if statement, if statement never breaks and loops indefinitely

Tags: python

I'm writing a coin toss function that only accepts "h" and "t" as input.

To do this I use an if statement to check if the input is "h", and one nested in it to check if it is "t".

If both conditions aren't met, it calls the function again.

The problem is that even if the first input is "t" or "h", it still calls the function no matter what I do?

```
def coin_flip():
    player_coin = raw_input("Choose heads (h) or tails (t)!: ").lower
    if player_coin != "h":
        if player_coin != "t":
            coin_flip()

    coin = randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        coin = "h"
    else:
        coin = "t"

    if player_coin == coin:
        print "You won the coin toss! You get to go first!"
        player_turn()

    else:
        print "You guessed the wrong answer! The Computer goes first!"
        comp_turn()
```

Comment: You should probably `return coin_flip()`

Comment: @MVChr thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the function again, just stick that part in a `while` loop with the following condition:

```
player_coin = None
while player_coin not in ('h', 't'):
    player_coin = raw_input("Choose heads (h) or tails (t)!: ").lower()
```

I used `x in tuple` instead of multiple checks, and made sure you're invoking `lower()` since it isn't in your example.